# "Not in list" error while using intersection

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I am trying to find a match between two lists with this code:

```
 def matching(text, symples, half2):
  for word in text:
    find = set(symples).intersection(word)

 indexNum = symples.index(find)
 print(indexNum)
 print(find)
```

I succeeded in finding the match between them.  I need to find the index number of the matching word in the list and when I try that I get an error message that the word was not found in the list.

I tried to print the matching word between the two lists `find` and it was printed with brackets ( `{}` or `[]` ).

Are the brackets the reason there was no match found in the list?

Comment: you have typos in your code `samples` and why are you passing `half2`. Also, please paste your error message and the values of what you called `maching` with.

Comment: the error message was ['lol'] is not in list , the idea is to take an input from a user and i stored it in text list , then see if any word in this text match any value in the symples list , like 'lol' or 'lmoa' and if the word is found , the explanation of the short cut is stored in half2 in the same index like 'lol' in index 0 in symples and there is 'laghing out loud' in index 0 in half2 list . i hope you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: Print type(find) and find itself, and that should tell you what you can not use it as an index.  if word in symples --> symples.index(word)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are are a couple reasons your code isn't working and you are right on about brackets being one reason.

The line `find = set(symples).intersection(word)` returns and assigns a `set` to the variable `find`. Later, when you try to find the index of find, it is not found because that set is not found in the list.

For example:

```python
symples = ['1','2','3']
word = '1'
find = set(symples).intersection(word) # find = {'1'}
indexNum = symples.index(find)         # not found because {'1'} is not in the list
```

To fix this, loop through the intersection set:

```python
find = set(symples).intersection(word)
for f in find:
    indexNum = symples.index(f)
    print(indexNum)
    print(f)
```

There are also a bunch of problems with the indentation in your code. The for loop keeps running, so `find` only ever has set with the intersection of the last word. If you want to print out each one, make sure you have the right indentation. Here is an example with the previous errors fixed as well:

```python
def matching(text, symples, half2):
    for word in text:
        find = set(symples).intersection(word)
        for f in find:
            indexNum = symples.index(f)
            print(indexNum)
            print(f)
```

HOWEVER, there are better ways to implement this...

1. Only take the intersection once.

   There's no reason to loop through text and take the intersection each time. Take the intersection of the two lists right away.

   ```python
   def matching(text, symples, half2):
       find = set(symples).intersection(text)
       for f in find:
           indexNum = symples.index(f)
           print(indexNum)
           print(f)
   ```
2. Loop through one list and check if each word is in the other list.

   ```python
   def matching(text, symples, half2):
       for word in symples:
           if word in text:
               indexNum = symples.index(word)
               print(indexNum)
               print(word)
   ```
3. Loop through one list and check if each word is in the other list, while keeping track of the index.

   ```python
   def matching(text, symples, half2):
       for indexNum, word in enumerate(symples):
           if word in text:
               print(indexNum)
               print(word)
   ```